# How to open a QR scanner from already developed application on Microsoft Surface

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, qr-code

Want to develop an application for Microsoft Surface that can open QR scanner, when the key focus on a textfield on another application.

But the challenge here I am facing is that I can't write any logic on the application where the textfield is. That is a form of other app.

What the user need, is to fill the field from the QR Code scanned result.

Any idea what kind of application is required for this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you describe your question more clearly so that we can understand it better.

Comment: Actually the application where I need to display the QR Code text is a SAP application and I can't write any logic on that. But the requirement is to fill the textfield of a form in SAP from QR code data. I don't understand what kind of app I should work on to access the QR data and fill it automatically on that textfield.

Comment: You can use [`ZXing.uwp`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.uwp/) to get QR code data.